# Restrict that only one person or one group is selected in a person/group picker in infopath 2007 form

Tags: infopath, forms-services

Is there a way to restrict that only one person or one group is selected in a person/group picker field for a web-based InfoPath 2007 form?

Example:
There is a web-based InfoPath form with one person/group picker field. When the user attempt to select more than 1 person or group, it will not be accepted in the form.

Comment: For SharePoint Server 2007 - in case anyone ask.